# Send FormData() using Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

There is an internal web application that accepts only formdata and we have an existing aura component that send the file to that web app.
here is the upload file action that executes when a upload button is clicked :

```
uploadFiles: function(component, event, helper) {
        let files = component.find('fileId').get('v.files');

        if (files == null || files.length == 0 || component.get('v.recordId') == null) {
            return false;
        }

        // disable Upload button while sending
        component.set('v.disableUpload', true);

         let xhrs = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhrs.open('POST', fileUploadURL, true);

           let data = new FormData();
            data.append('salesforce-upload', files);
            data.append('record-id', component.get('v.recordId'));

            // create state change closure
            xhrs.onreadystatechange = () => {
                // skip change if not done (4)
                if (xhrs.readyState !== 4) {
                    return;
                }

                if (xhrs.status === 200) {
               alert('File Uploaded Successfully');
                } else {
               alert('Upload Failed'+xhrs.status);               
                }
            };

            xhrs.send(data);
        
    }
```

I have a requirement to Send the pdf file using the apex class to that web app.

I tried multiple ways to manually create formdata but it is throwing internal server error(500).
How can I send the below formdata using apex. Please advise.

```
let data = new FormData();
            data.append('salesforce-upload', files);
            data.append('record-id', component.get('v.recordId'));
```

here is my apex method:

```
public static void sendFileToPortal(String datafile,string filename,string recordId){
System.debug('datafile-->'+datafile);

Blob formData = HttpHexFormBuilder.build()
        .writeParam( 'record-id', recordId )
        .writeFile( 'file', filename,  datafile  )
        .getFormAsBlob();

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://staging-suppliers.cityfibre.com/file-upload');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW');
req.setBodyAsBlob(formData);
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

// Print the response code
System.debug('Response Code: ' + res.getStatusCode());

// Print the response body
System.debug('Response Body: ' + res.getBody());
     
    
system.debug('formData-->'+formData);
}
```

I got this HttpHexFormBuilder class from this git link: [here](https://github.com/nicolas1bruno/multipart-data-apex-request/blob/master/HttpHexFormBuilder.cls).